# What best time complexity to find maximum and minimum element in an array at the same time?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, time-complexity

I am new to this platform and not sure is this question been asked before or not but I find this quite interesting that what would be the best way to find the Largest and smallest element in array, is it O(2N) N+N for each iteration or performing quick or merge sort to sort the array and access the last index  of array and very first index of array.

I think Performing Quick or Merge sort is better because its `(N*Log(N))` and both smallest and largest will be able to get at once. And it's because `2N > (n*Log(N)`.

Am I thinking it right or not just need confirmation.

Thank you.

Comment: 1. `2n` is *not* more complex than `n log(n)`. Simple to verify `log(n)` *grows* with `n`. And for `n > 4` it's larger than `2`. Therefore `2n > n*log(n)` for only `0 >= n >= 3` 2. With complexity analysis, all constants are dropped anyway `O(2n)` is simplified to `O(n)` as only the growth rate is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just make a sweep and save the min and max?

```py
maximum = -sys.maxsize - 1
minimum = sys.maxsize

for elem in arr:
   if elem < minimum:
      minimum = elem
   elif elem > maximum:
      maximum = elem
```

Would this suit your purposes?